# Filedialog is killing my thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

Im working on a **socket** program in Java.
Im running a **GUI** with a socket server in the background.
The **socket** server is running a **thread** that checks for **socket** messages every 10ms.
Both of them runs fine together but as soon as I try to open my File dialog in the **gui**, the **gui** crashes, but the server keeps on running.
Im thinking that I run the server (or the server **thread**) in a wrong way.
The file dialog works fine if I skip the **socket**.

What could be the problem, could it be that Im running the thread in a wrong way?

(this in one class)

```
public ServerController(){
        ServSocket st = new ServSocket();
    Thread thread1=new Thread(st);
    thread1.start();
    }
```

(this is my thread)

```
public void run(){
    while (true) {
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        switch (Status) {
        case CONNECTED:
            try {

                socket = new Socket(hostIP, port);
                System.out.println("Connected on: " + hostIP + port);

                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                changeStatus(STARTSENDING, true);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("disconnected");
            }
            break;
```

(and this is my main)

```
 static ServerController scon;
 static Controller cn;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     scon = new ServerController();
      cn = new Controller();
     cn.gui();


      }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it is hard to say what happens there.

Comment: Some more information on "gui crashes" needed (exception? freeze?)

Comment: The Gui freezes, but the server runs fine, no exceptions or error messages what so ever, what more part of the code could be useful?

Comment: What does the file dialog do? Where is it called from?

Comment: The file dialog gets opened from a JMenu in the GUI, it is suppose to choose a file and "getName" + "getAbsolutePath", and in further thoughts in suppose to send the name and path in a message through the socket server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now solved.
Seems that the problem was that i had a scanner that was waiting for input(`string = sc.next();`) every 10ms in the thread, and after a few input my GUI showed.
I removed the Scanner and i now have a working application.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing here, but I think it's relating to the EDT.

Are you trying to launch the dialog from outside the EDT? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread

If you think you might be, try using SwingUtilities static methods (specifically isEventDispatchThread and invokeLater) to hone in and rectify the issue:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread()

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)

hth