# JFileChooser launch problems

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am having problems starting any application on my development machine that uses the 'JFileChooser' Swing object. When I originally developed the application and tested it , the File Chooser window opened and everything was fine but like after a week , I tried running the app again and nothing would show at all.

At first I thought it was a Threading problem( My original app used a little multi-threading), so I coped and pasted the following code ( I got the code from the Internet ) to test it out:

```
package com.kwm.util.test;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Demo");


    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\tmp"));

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("Show Dialog");
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fc.showDialog(frame, "Choose");
        }
    });
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Show Open Dialog");
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File[] selectedfiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedfiles.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(selectedfiles[i].getName() + "\n");
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, sb.toString());
            }

        }
    });
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Show Save Dialog");
    btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fc.showSaveDialog(frame);

        }
    });

    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
    pane.add(btn1);
    pane.add(btn2);
    pane.add(btn3);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And still I see nothing. I am guessing the Machine has a problem but am unable to identify what the problem is.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
The OS Version is Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Version, SP1

The Java version is : 1.5.0_12 ( both JDK and JRE)

I am also afraid that this may be related to a Network problem... JFileChooser is looking for a network directory and the DNS may be conflicting. Is there a way to check this? Maybe check what JVM is logging?

Comment: If you suspect your system is the culprit, information about your PC could be useful. (OS? JRE version? etc.)

Comment: Probably not the cause of the immediate problem, but Swing GUIs should be constructed on the EDT.

Comment: @Andrew: What do you mean by 'Swing GUIs should be constructed on the EDT. '? A URL would be helpful.. Please also note that the code snippet above was simply used to test whether the problem was from my original application or a machine-related cause. Thanks.

Comment: See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) lesson in the Java Tutorial for details.  Quote from that page "The *event dispatch thread*, where all event-handling code is executed. Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also execute on this thread."

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

@Andrew Thompson is right: starting on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) may not be the problem, but related bugs are notoriously protean and difficult to reproduce. For reference, I've a shown a common re-factoring below. It tested successfully on Mac OS X 10.5, using

```
$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_28"
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() throws HeadlessException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Demo");
        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\tmp"));
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fc.showDialog(frame, "Choose");
            }
        });
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Show Open Dialog");
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File[] selectedfiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedfiles.length; i++) {
                        sb.append(selectedfiles[i].getName());
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, sb.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Show Save Dialog");
        btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fc.showSaveDialog(frame);
            }
        });
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
        pane.add(btn1);
        pane.add(btn2);
        pane.add(btn3);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note changes involving `sb.append()` and `frame.pack()`, which should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with JFileChooser when using threads, uploaded a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366602/filedialog-is-killing-my-thread). I got a lot of help by reading this wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread (although its already been mentiond). 
My problem was that I had a scanner that was running in the thread, always waiting for input before showing GUI.